# Xamarin custom renderer with different parent control

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, custom-renderer

So want to render out of box CarouselView when Android and CarouselViewFormsPlugin when iOS. I know can accomplish this in xaml using onplatform but don't want to have to do that in several places. Can this be done using custom Renderer like following?

Core Project:

```
public class CustomCarousel{}
```

Android:

```
public class CustomCarousel:CarouselView{}
```

iOS

```
public class CustomCarousel:CarouselView.Plugin{}
```

If this is not possible i have two options that i can see:

1. In xaml use onplatform to determine which control to use.
2. Have a different view for iOS and Android and determine at runtime which view to render.

I know i can implement these two options but i think that if possible CustomRenderer is best solution here?

Comment: If you use custom renderer to achieve it, you must inherit the `CarouselPageRenderer`, So it is cannot be used like `public class CustomCarousel:CarouselView.Plugin{}` format.

Comment: Yes that is conclusion i came to which does not work so ended up just doing onplatform in the xaml to render respective control

Comment: Ok. Just achieve it in the xaml.